# Finding a random sample of unique data across multiple columns - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Given a set of data in a SQL Server database with the following columns

```
AccountID, UserID_Salesperson, UserID_Servicer1, UserID_Servicer2
```

All three columns are primary keys from the same users table. I need to find a random sample that will include every `UserID` available in all three columns no matter the position while guaranteeing the fewest unique `AccountID`'s possible.

```
--SET UP TEST DATA
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE 
(
    AccountID int, 
    UserID_Salesperson int, 
    UserID_Servicer1 int, 
    UserID_Servicer2 int
)

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (AccountID, UserID_Salesperson, UserID_Servicer1, UserID_Servicer2) 
VALUES (12345, 1, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (AccountID, UserID_Salesperson, UserID_Servicer1, UserID_Servicer2) 
VALUES (12346, 3, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (AccountID, UserID_Salesperson, UserID_Servicer1, UserID_Servicer2) 
VALUES (12347, 4, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (AccountID, UserID_Salesperson, UserID_Servicer1, UserID_Servicer2) 
VALUES (12348, 1, 2, 3)

--VIEW THE NEW TABLE
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE

--NORMALIZE DATA (Unique List of UserID's) 
SELECT DISTINCT MyDistinctUserIDList 
FROM
    (SELECT UserID_Salesperson as MyDistinctUserIDList, 'Sales' as Position 
     FROM MY_TABLE
     UNION 
     SELECT UserID_Servicer1, 'Service1' as Position 
     FROM MY_TABLE
     UNION 
     SELECT UserID_Servicer2, 'Service2' as Position 
     FROM MY_TABLE) MyDerivedTable

--NORMALIZED DATA
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT AccountID, UserID_Salesperson as MyDistinctUserIDList, 'Sales' as Position 
     FROM MY_TABLE
     UNION 
     SELECT AccountID, UserID_Servicer1, 'Service1' as Position 
     FROM MY_TABLE
     UNION 
     SELECT AccountID, UserID_Servicer2, 'Service2' as Position 
     FROM MY_TABLE) MyDerivedTable

DROP TABLE MY_TABLE
```

For this example table, I could select `AccountID` (12347 and 12348) OR (12347 and 12346) to get the least accounts with all users.

My current solution is inefficient and can make mistakes. I currently select a random `AccountID`, insert the data into a temp table and try to find the next insert from something I have not already put in the temp table. I loop through the records until it finds something not used before… and after a few thousand loops it will give up and select any record.

Comment: There may not exist such a sample at all, depending on your data, or there may be only one unique arrangement, which could hardly be called random, or determining what the "fewest IDs possible" are may be prohibitively expensive to guarantee. Why not just drop the idea of randomness and use either generated sample data that meets your requirements by definition, or (if the use of real data is a requirement for some reason) queries that are strictly deterministic and use things like `ROW_NUMBER()` and `TOP`?

Comment: Random Sampling is harder than most think.  To get a viable sample, it requires equal parts Science and Black Magic.  Stratified Sampling will tend to generate the best results, but determining the strata is a process in itself and there is no one answer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert my business requirements is to have a random selection of accounts where every user has at least on account audited. Given that audits take many hours its very beneficial to have the least number of audits as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you guarantee the fewest account ids, but you can get one row per user id using:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by UserId order by newid()) as seqnum
      from my_table t cross apply
           (values (t.UserID_Salesperson), (t.UserID_Servicer1), (t.UserID_Servicer2)
           ) v(UserID)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your original table doesn't have a primary key.  Assuming that there is one row per account, you can dedup this so it doesn't have duplicate accounts:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by UserId order by newid()) as seqnum
      from my_table t cross apply
           (values (t.UserID_Salesperson), (t.UserID_Servicer1), (t.UserID_Servicer2)
           ) v(UserID)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by row_number() over (partition by accountID order by accountID);
```

Comment: . . .  Does second version work without `order by` ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . No.  That is just a trick to avoid an additional subquery.  It is generally not the most efficient way of implementing the logic, but without knowing if `AccountId` is unique, I decided to take "amount of typing" into account.

Comment: @Gordon-linoff Yes, the AccountID is unique. I tried the examples above and I can't get the 2nd snippet to run. I tried the following with your example to get a unique list of accountid's 
```
SELECT AccountID, Count(*) FROM (select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by UserId order by newid()) as seqnum
      from my_table t cross apply
           (values (t.UserID_Salesperson), (t.UserID_Servicer1), (t.UserID_Servicer2)
           ) v(UserID)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1) dt
GROUP BY dt.AccountID
HAVING Count(*) = 1 ```
Results Vary when executed

Comment: @Kevin . . . Of course the result vary.  The ordering is random.